# I need a function that reads names and makes a top of the most used

Tags: c++

As the title says, the function must read the list of names (vec2) count how many times a name is repeated (example: ana - 5) and show the "n" most repeated names

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

ifstream ent;
ofstream sal;

vector<string> LeerVec(vector<string> vec0, int c);
vector<string> EscribirVec(vector<string> vec2);

int main(){
//preparo los archivos
ent.open("nombres.in");
sal.open("nombres.out");

int c, n;
vector<string> A;
ent>>c >>n; 

A=LeerVec(A, c);
A=EscribirVec(A);

ent.close();
sal.close();

return 0;
}

vector<string> LeerVec(vector<string> vec0, int c){
string palabra;

for(int i=0;i<c;i++){
    ent>> palabra;
    vec0.push_back(palabra);
    }
    
return vec0;
}

vector<string>EscribirVec(vector<string> vec2){
vector<int> Nums;
vector<string> vec3;
int cont=1;

sort(vec2.begin(), vec2.end()); 

for(int i=0;i<vec2.size();i++){
    if(vec2[i]==vec2[i+1]){
        cont+=1;
        cout<<"("<<cont<<") "; //Test
        }

    if(vec2[i]!=vec2[i+1]){
        for(int i=0;i<vec2.size();i++){
            vec3.push_back(vec2[i]); 
            Nums.push_back(cont);
            }
            
        cout<<vec3[i]<<" ["<<Nums[i]<<"] "<<endl; //Test
        cont=1; // reinicia
        }
    }
    
return vec3;
}
```

The file is "nombres.in" and it says:

```
25 3
Ana
Ricardo
Juan
Ester
Juana
Pedro
Federico
Juan
Ismael
Juan
Ana
Pilar
Juan
Ana
Juana
Ana
Ricardo
Juan
Manuel
Juana
Pilar
Juana
Ana
Juan
Juan
```

Nombres.out should have the top of the names. If I wanted to show the top 3 the exit would be:

```
Ana 5
Juan 7
Juana 4
```

I don't know what is wrong, the variable "Nums" should save the counter when there are different names, however it always saves "5", in addition, there is a name that does not show

Comment: Your code [miserably fails to compile](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ba115fccd99d6db5). Give us a [mcve] that reproduces the problem as required here please.

Comment: what is the input? what is in the files? what is the output?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ i put the changes, sorry for the inconvenience

Answer (score 1):

You must not enter the second loop with iterator 'i' again.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<string> vec2 = { "A", "A", "A", "B", "C", "B"};
    vector<int> Nums;
    vector<string> vec3;
    int cont=1;

    sort(vec2.begin(), vec2.end());

    for(int i=0;i<vec2.size();i++)
    {
        if(vec2[i]==vec2[i+1]){
            cont+=1;
        }
        else
        {
            vec3.push_back(vec2[i]); //save 1 name
            Nums.push_back(cont); //save the cont
            cont=1; // restart cont
        }
    }
    for(int i=0;i<vec3.size();i++)
    {
        cout<<vec3[i]<<" ["<<Nums[i]<<"] "<<endl;
    }

    // ***** see comment below 
}
```

At the marker, you need to perfom the final task: sort Nums alongside with vec3 and output the first three entries.
Therefor I would collect results in a vector of structs (int,string) or better: a dictionary to get the output by sorting / readout.

Comment: I tried what you said but it does not work for me, there I published the rest of the code, sorry for the inconvenience

Answer (score 1):

As Jens has already given you the error. I would like to show a nicer way to combat this problem would be to use [Maps](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/map-associative-containers-the-c-standard-template-library-stl/)

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <algorithm>

bool sortByVal(const std::pair<std::string, int> &a, const std::pair<std::string, int> &b)
{
    return (a.second > b.second);
}



int main(){
    std::map<std::string,int> name_table;
    std::vector<std::pair<std::string,int>> all_names;
    std::vector<std::string> names{"Travis","Anna","Anna","Scott","Travis","Travis","Lang","Shin","Shin"};
    for(const auto name:names)  ++name_table[name];

    for(auto it:name_table){
        all_names.push_back(std::make_pair(it.first,it.second));
    }

    std::sort(all_names.begin(),all_names.end(),sortByVal);


    /// You now have the top 3

    std::cout << "Print top : ";
    int number_of_names;
    std::cin >> number_of_names;

    for(const auto i:all_names){
        if (number_of_names != 0){
            std::cout << i.first << '\n';
            --number_of_names;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: This is why I considered the question quite good in fact (and do not agree to downvote it outright): it has several levels of learning experience. First there is a programming bug to fix (what I did) but on the next level, there is the problem how to avoid these bugs altogether by a better design (your answer).

Comment: @Jens I think the main issue is the structure of the question and the fact that it misses a good [mre]. Anyway I think our answers have helped him solve his issue, especially yours as you solved the bug, that's why I upvoted your answer. If you really really think the question is good you might as well edit and improve it